# Example of automorphism $\sigma$ and $\alpha \in O_K$ such that $\alpha$ and $\sigma(\alpha)$ are not associates?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to solve an exercise from last year's exam:

Let $p$ be a prime number, let $ζ$ be a primitive $p$-th root of unity, and let $K = \mathbb{Q}(ζ)$. 
I am looking for an example for a prime $p$ and $\alpha \in O_K$ and a Galois automorphism $\sigma$ such that $\alpha$ and $\sigma(\alpha)$ are not associates.

I am fairly new to number theory so what I have so far is quite basic: I think $O_K = \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ and am guessing the $\alpha$ we are interested in will be $\alpha = \zeta$? But don't know where to go from here. I think in general the Galois automorphism for the extension of rationals by a $p$-th root of unity fixes $1$ and sends each $\zeta \rightarrow \zeta^k$ for $1≤k≤p-1$?

Comment: What do you mean by "$\alpha$ and $\sigma(\alpha)$ are not associates"? Your thought that $O_K = \mathbb Z[\zeta]$ and the description of the Galois automorphisms are correct.

Comment: @Marktmeister the definition of associates I have is: elements $f$ and $g$ are associate if $f=g\mu$ for some invertible element $\mu \in O^{\times}_{K}$

Comment: Ah, of course. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $p = 3$. Then $[K:\mathbb Q] = 2$ and so there is exactly one pair of complex conjugate embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb C$. By [Dirichlet's Unit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_unit_theorem), the rank of $O_K^\times = \mathbb Z[\zeta]^\times$ is $0$. Hence $O_K^\times$ is torsion and coincides with the group of roots of unity in $K$. It follows that
$$O_K^\times = \{\pm 1,\; \pm \zeta,\; \pm\zeta^2 \}.$$
Now, let $\alpha := -1+ 2\zeta$ and $\sigma$ be such that $\sigma(\zeta) = \zeta^2$. Then $\sigma(\alpha) = -1+2\zeta^2 = -3 - 2\zeta$, where we used  $1 + \zeta + \zeta^2 = 0$. Now we calculate that

$$\sigma(\alpha) \neq \pm \alpha,$$
$$\zeta \cdot \sigma(\alpha) = -3\zeta-2\zeta^2 = 2-\zeta \neq \pm \alpha,$$
$$\zeta^2 \cdot \sigma(\alpha) = -3\zeta^2 - 2 = 1+3\zeta \neq \pm \alpha.$$

Hence our choice of $p$, $\sigma$ and $\alpha$ satisfies what we want.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't expect $\alpha$ to be $\zeta$.
As you pointed out, $\zeta$ will be sent to some $\zeta^{k}$ and they are both invertible in $\mathcal{O}_{K}$, thus associate !